# Indecomposable representations of quivers of finite fields

Tags: rt.representation-theory, quivers

Given a path algebra $A=KQ$ with a wild quiver $Q$ over a finite field.
There should be only a finite number of indecomposable modules of a given dimension for the algebra $A$. Are there example of such $Q$ where all indecomposables have been classified?
Let $Q$ be the $n$-Kroenecker quiver for $n \geq 2$ and let $K$ be a field with $q$ elements. Let $a_{n,s,q}$ be the number of indecompoable represenations of this quiver of dimension $s$. Is $a_{n,s,q}$ known (at least for special values)?

Comment: Here are some relevant references: "Counting Representations of Quivers over Finite Fields" by Hua, and a series of papers by Hausel--Letellier--Rodriguez-Villegas: "Arithmetic harmonic analysis on character and quiver varieties I and II", "Positivity for Kac polynomials and DT-invariants of quivers".